# Making a super efficient line following robot that runs on super capacitors for as long as possible

Tags: arduino, low-power, robotics

I'm trying to make a line following robot that runs for at least 20 seconds on a 2F super capacitor (5x 2.7V 10F super capacitors in series with protection circuits.) So I'm working with 13.5V and 182 Joules of energy.

My first thought was to use an Atmega8A in standalone configuration that draws almost 18mA. But the Arduino Nano draws around 20mA peak, so I decided to use an Arduino Nano and replace its 5V regulator and get a 3.3V one. I'll be using a QTR-8A IR sensor array that draws about 60-70mA. Both the Nano and the IR sensor array will run at 3.3V.

I'm confused about the motor drivers and motors.

I know I should've made my plans around the motors as these are going to draw the most amount of current.

My entire robot's weight is about 400gm. I was thinking about using the 12V 220RPM pololu micro metal gear motors but I'm not so sure. As for the motor drivers, I was thinking of using a TB6612FNG. I don't actually know if other good alternatives exist. So, I need some suggestions for regarding the motors and the motor drivers.

What do you guys think of my setup? I'll also appreciate some suggestions on how I can conserve more power for better runtime of my robot.

Comment: why supercaps. Batteries are better

Comment: It's actually for a competition. The bots are only allowed to use a maximum capacitance of 2F. And the robot that goes the furthest in the track wins.

Comment: do some basic physics conservation of energy and motor PWM computations with current and torque. Minimize acceleration, mass & friction and choose an some efficient vehicle and use a BMS for the string

Comment: "runs for at least 20 seconds...  the robot that goes the **furthest** in the track wins." - if the goal is distance, why are you concerned about time? How far do you expect it to go in 20 seconds?

Comment: Forget the ATmega's. They are power hogs. Find something truly lower power. However, that said, you really need to work out where the energy is really being spent and prioritize your attention to the largest expenditures. It's likely that motors, weight, and friction losses unrelated to useful motion are the larger issues. So probably find very efficient motors (they exist, now) and learn how best to utilize them. Then work your way down from there.

Comment: Additionally, some microcontrollers have low power modes where GPIO and timers are still active, depending on your sensors you may be able to operate in a near shutdown state. Depending on speed sensor may not need to constantly output, can maybe request data once every 10ms or so.

Comment: For maximum power transfer you want matched electro-mechanical impedances but only get 50% efficiency max. For max efficiency and thus conservation of energy, you want the lightest load current possible and lightest mass with lowest friction. And use PWM at a suitable frequency to minimize eddy current and conduction losses. Capiche? no uC needed.  (Optional) Just an analog IR steering mechanism with low pulse power on IR and steering pulse correction then  low speed so that braking is not needed. Yes there will be a minimum load needed to make maximum efficiency due to friction and losses.

Comment: My guess no more than 10% PWM current with no gears on 2 wheel drive. And current for directional steering depends on speed, friction and idle losses. YOu can test this on a battery and monitor using some wireless method like I to F pulsed to a tiny speaker. Quick and dirty  to monitor current 50~100mV drop max . Steering servo ought to be low current when not driven but depends on hysteresis.

Comment: The same thought experiment exists in a car running out of gas.

Comment: Here's another hint: turn off the sensor 90% of the time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The capacitor's voltage drops as current is drawn from it. Assuming constant power draw, the voltage curve (green line) should look like this (simulated with [LTspice](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/design-tools-and-calculators/ltspice-simulator.html)):-

[image]

In this example a 2F capacitor is discharged from 13.5 V to 0 V at a constant power of 5 watts, reaching 3.5 V in 34 seconds. At this point the capacitor has delivered 93% of the theoretical energy available. If the power draw is lower then the time increases in inverse proportion, eg. at 2.5 W it should last 72 seconds.

You could run 12 V motors directly off the capacitor, but since the end voltage is 3.5 V to get constant speed you would have to continuously adjust the PWM ratio to produce the equivalent of 3.5 V, and the motors would run at ~3.5/12 = 29% of full speed.

Alternatively you could feed the capacitor into a buck-mode DC/DC converter set for 3.3 V output. A good converter should have efficiency of >=90%, which may be more efficient than than reducing motor speed with PWM. At 3.5 V the input current for 5 W output power rises to ~1.5 A, so you would need a converter rated for >1.5 A.

However depending on how efficiently your robot can roll, you may need much less than 5 watts. The [Polulu 50:1 MP 6V](https://www.pololu.com/product/2365) should do ~230 rpm at 3.3 V, drawing ~0.17A and 0.55 W at maximum power. But no-load current is only ~0.04 A per motor, so the actual current draw for 2 motors could be somewhere between 0.08 A and 0.34 A.

At lower motor current the consumption of your IR sensor array could become significant, so it might be better to use higher power motors that drive the robot faster, putting more of the total power into traction (assuming the robot can steer reliably at the faster speed) and less into the control circuit.

If you take the regulator and power LED off an Arduino Nano and run it from the internal RC clock you can easily get the current draw below 1mA, which is insignificant compared to the other components.

Answer (score 0):

Start by paying attention to *every part* of the design:

- Microcontroller - Use the lowest-power one you can find, that still meets your requirements. Make the clock speed and voltage as low as possible. (The microcontroller might use less power on a lower voltage, even when you count the heat wasted in the voltage regulator)
- Sensor - 70mA is quite a lot. Keep it turned off as much as possible. You don't need to continuously look at the line, you only need to check it often enough that you don't lose track of the line. Also see if it will still work on a lower voltage (e.g. with a resistor in series).
- Motors - compare different ones, and calculate the efficiency at different speeds. You need the most distance per joule; you don't care if it's really slow. But not too slow, because then the other parts will use more energy by being turned on for longer.
- Try to coast when turning. Don't just stop one wheel - that wastes kinetic energy.
- Capacitors have very low internal resistance, so they can source lots of current even at a low voltage. If you make a boost converter, you might be able to suck it all the way dry instead of stopping when it's still got a few volts in it. You can use your microcontroller to control the converter.
- Speaking of that, how will you get the microcontroller voltage when the cap is fully charged? You'll probably use a linear regulator which wastes power. You *may* be able to use a buck converter - also controlled by the microcontroller itself after it starts up - to power the microcontroller and sensor. But your microcontroller probably won't draw much power, so the linear regulator *might* be more efficient. If you have time, try both.
- Put a solar panel on top. There are lights on the ceiling, yes? (Only joking, because that's probably cheating)

Cool project, and good luck!